# After adding skip-innodb mysql doesn't start

Tags: mysql, debian, innodb

I am trying to setup these values:

```
#skip-bdb
#skip-locking
#skip-innodb
```

When I add them to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and even if I turn ON of of, them after I do the service restart mysql fails to start, and no error message printed.

```
sudo service mysql restart
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
[FAIL] Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

Previously I made sure that I have no InnoDB tables, and all files of that type were removed.

I tried looking for error files but I couldn't locate it:

- `/var/log/mysql.err` is a 0 byte file
- `/var/log/mysql` folder has no files

`rsyslog` was changed in past with `inetutils-syslogd`, and this might have changed the log files, and it could be the reason why I don't see any error logs, and I am stuck how to look or go forward.

Comment: On debian, mysql logs to syslog, so check other files in /var/log too

Comment: You can stop mysql from using syslog by removing the file /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf

Comment: OK I removed that and gave a try, and nothing visible on the screen, and files were not changed in the log directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax has changed.  Assuming you are trying to disable InnoDB so that you can use the MyISAM storage provider instead, here's how you do that.  Instead of `skip-innodb`, put

```
innodb=OFF
default_storage_engine=MyISAM
```

in your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` (under the `[mysqld]` section).  Note that you need both: the new syntax for disabling InnoDB is `innodb=OFF`, but you also need to specify some other default storage engine to replace InnoDB.  To verify that this has been successful, restart MySQL and run

```
mysqladmin -u root -p var | grep have_innodb
```

You should see the result

```
| have_innodb                                       | DISABLED              |
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/11772814/781723.

I don't know what the equivalent is for `skip-bdb` or `skip-locking`.

Comment: This is correct for newer versions. I am using; Server version:  5.5.35-0+wheezy1 (Debian)

Answer (score 2):

None of those options are available in current mysql packages.  Having any of those would cause mysql to fail to start.  If you want to see the error, you can run `mysqld` by itself by hand as root in a shell, and I'd expect to see it die when it encounters the first of these invalid options.

You can get a list of the available config parameters by running `mysqld --help --verbose` on the command line.  `mysqld --help --verbose | grep skip` should also confirm that these options are no longer available.